# how to fix issue sometims load page get error js?

Tags: magento2

I have installed magento 2.1.7 version. Now I get error sometime I reload page get error [image]

sometimes get another js error and sometime is good. I have tried deploy but not change. so pls let me how to fix this.

Note: In backend panel I had set merge and Minify JavaScript Files.

Thank advance!

Comment: If you are unset merge & minify  javaScript then working fine?

Comment: I had similar issues. Try using the "Clear cache storage" button, to completely purge the cache.

Comment: @Abdul in localhost all work good.

Comment: @Lez I tried but the issues not resolve.